# Ansible: compose list of facts in jinja template

Tags: templates, jinja2, ansible

I am setting up a cluster service with Ansible 1.9.2 and need to configure a JSON config file with a list of cluster servers to join.

Currently, I have this working as below. It produces correct, if ugly, output.

```
{
    ...
    "join": [
{% for host in groups['cluster'] %}
        "{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
],
    ...
}
```

Is it possible for Ansible to create a list of specific host facts, or for Jinja to compose a list dynamically? I would hope for something I can leave in my template like this:

```
{
    ...
    "join": {{ list_of_cluster_ips|to_nice_json }},
    ...
}
```

I tried some Jinja magic at the top of the template file to generate the list as below:

```
{% set list_of_cluster_ips = [] %}
{% for host in groups['cluster'] %}
    {% do list_of_cluster_ips.append(host) %}
{% endfor %}
{
    ...
    "join": {{ list_of_cluster_ips|to_nice_json }},
    ...
}
```

But Ansible doesn't support the 'do' function of Jinja and fails with `fatal: [cluster-1] => {'msg': "AnsibleError: file: <template>, line number: 3, error: Encountered unknown tag 'do'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.", 'failed': True}`.

Is there a way for Ansible to generate the list that can be used in the template?

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic inventory? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{%- set list_of_cluster_ips = [] %}
{%- for host in groups['cluster'] %}
    {%- if list_of_cluster_ips.append(hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']) %}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
{
    ...
    "join": {{ list_of_cluster_ips|to_nice_json }},
    ...
}
```

Comment: I guess minus signs should be placed a different way. `{% if ... -%} {%- endif %}` works for me pretty well. Though it's sad that `do` is not supported, so this looks like a hack.